# Spring security re-authentication on some pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Are there any ways to force re-authentication with Spring security when user performs some very sensitive operations on particular pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Or

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

and

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
  session.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session-based authentication.You may use something like that for this purposes:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .rememberMe()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/logout")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/my-profile")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);

}
```

Spring Security automatically redirects to login page if user preforms not permited requiest. That's why to redirect to logout `.loginPage("/logout")`, and than redirect to login page after logout `.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")`